# Prevent extra whitespaces from appearing on fwrite?

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a file with fopen and write and write multiple lines in it, however I'm not sure what's the correct way to make sure the lines don't have incorrect spaces carried out from PHP. Doing this:

```
    $content= 'Line
              Another line
              Another line
              Another line
              Another line
              Another line';
        $fh = fopen(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."/myfile.txt", 'w');
        fwrite($fh, $content);
        fclose($fh);
```

Produces white spaces to the left of the document. To prevent the white spaces from appearing I started doign this:

```
        $content= PHP_EOL.'Line'.
                  PHP_EOL.'Another line'.
                  PHP_EOL.'Another line'.
                  PHP_EOL.'Another line'.
                  PHP_EOL.'Another line'.
                  PHP_EOL.'Another line';
```

But it's not very easy to read. Is there a simpler way to prevent this whitespaces from appearing on created files?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc :)

Comment: @Leri: in this regard, behaves like the other quotations... - http://codepad.org/VwqOuXx8

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Manual has clear example what OP should be doing. Also heredoc syntax is much clear for multiline string.

Comment: @Leri: 1) can != should 2) as long as you don't have quoting issues... no, not really. saying that's is a much clearer syntax is a bit of a stretch (to put it mildly).. a lot of developers never even heard about it.

Comment: I read the documentation, but it seems to me that there is no real advantage (in my case) to using quotes as I still have to break the indentation rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop indentation rules for multiline strings.

```
    $content= 'Line
Another line
Another line';
```

This a common practice in many languages - as the problem isn't really PHP specific.

Comment: that's what I'm doing right now but I find it very annoying, I thought there was a solution

Comment: Sorry, just stated the obvious... oh, well: remove it (see the preg_replace solution) or put it in a template in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You could use heredoc like Leri said or a regular expression to replace all the white spaces where there is more then one consecutive white space:

`$content = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", "", $content);`